# Activate USB Ports on CM4 with Debian Bullseye

Tags: debian, compute-module, compute-module-4

I want to use Debian on my Compute Module 4 instead of the Raspberry Pi OS:
2021.08.23 11 (Bullseye) 4 4 (4GB) from [raspi.debian.net](https://raspi.debian.net/tested/20210823_raspi_4_bullseye.img.xz)

source: [jeffgeerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2020/usb-20-ports-not-working-on-compute-module-4-check-your-overlays)

With the Raspberry Pi OS the following has do be done to activate the USB-Ports for the CM4:
To enable the USB 2.0 ports on the Compute Module 4, you need to edit the boot config file (/boot/config.txt) and add:

dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host

But:
After the flash operation I mount the CM4‘s EMMC again and see two partitions:
RASPIFIRM, where some dbt files and also a config.txt are located.

RASPIROOT, where the filesystem is located and also a /boot/firmware folder.

I created the config.txt in both location with the dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=host content but this did not work.

Has anyone succefully used Debian on CM4 with USB?
Thanks

Comment: no need to create the file in both places as the boot/firmware folder is a mount point for the raspifirm partition. Is there any particular reason you want to use debian instead of raspberry pi OS?

Comment: I also tried it one by one in both files. But it doesn't work.
With Raspberry Pi OS it works without any problems. So it's not a hardware problem.

The reason to use Debian is that I then can install a supported version of Home Assistant Supervisor